# App Engine - ReferenceProperty and custom indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datamodel

This is a follow-up question to Drew Sears' answer to this discussion:

[App Engine Datastore - Data Model question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314721/app-engine-datastore-data-model-question)

If I model bucket as a reference property in the object kind and say I want to query for objects in bucket 1234 with size > 1000. My query will look like "where bucket = key('Bucket', 1234) and size > 1000".

I'm assuming that this will require a custom index on the bucket and size properties. Is that assumption wrong? If not, is Model #2 in the original question (dynamic kinds) the only way to make it work with automatic indexes? I hope there's another way.

Thanks,
Keyur

Comment: Why are you so opposed to a custom index?

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question, my objects can have arbitrary properties and I need all of them to be individually queryable. If I were to create a custom index for each property, I'll run out of my quota of 200 custom indexes pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct: This will require a custom index. Dynamic kinds would be one way around this - though a kludgy one - but there may be others. Can you tell us more about the structure of these entities, the kinds of properties users can declare, and valid queries on those properties?

Comment: Bucket owners define the structure of objects in that bucket. Example object structures: (name, size), (name, length, description, read_only), etc. Example queries: size > 1000 (on the 1st structure), length > 1000 (2nd structure), read_only = false (2nd structure again)

Comment: But only ever one filter on one property in a bucket?

Comment: Yes. If ever I filter on more than one I'll either apply a secondary filter in memory or issue 2 queries.